# How to fix image not showing up in canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, promise

I'm trying to place an image in my canvas so I can use it in a little game I'm making in JS to practice functional programming.

I searched for some tutorials on promises and functional programming but haven't found a solution yet.

This is my code:

```
function loadImage(url) {

    return new Promise(resolve => {
        const image = new Image();
        image.addEventListener('load', () => {
            resolve(image);
        });
        image.src = url;
    });
}

const canvas = document.getElementById('bitchinBlock')
const context= canvas.getContext('2d');

context.scale(20, 20);

loadImage('media/images/ball.png')
    .then(image => {
    context.drawImage(image, 100, 100);
    });

const cube = [
    [1, 1],
    [1, 1]
];

function collide(arena, player) {

    const [c, o] = [player.cube, player.pos];
    for (let y = 0; y < c.length; ++y) {
        for (let x=0; x < c[y].length; ++x) {
            if (c[y][x] !== 0 &&
               (arena [y + o.y] &&
               arena[y + o.y][x + o.x]) !== 0) {
                   console.log(true);
                   return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}

function createMatrix(w, h) {
    const matrix = [];
    while (h--) {
        matrix.push(new Array(w).fill(0));   
    }
    return matrix;
}

function merge(arena, player) {

    player.cube.forEach((row, y) => {
        row.forEach((value, x) => {
            if (value !== 0) {
                arena[y + player.pos.y][x + player.pos.x] = value;
            }
        });
    });
}


function draw() {
    context.fillStyle = '#0b033f';
    context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    drawCube(player.cube, player.pos);



}


function drawCube(cube, offset){

    cube.forEach((row, y) => {
        row.forEach((value, x) => {
            if (value !== 0) {
                context.fillStyle = '#ff3dff';
                context.fillRect( x + offset.x,
                                  y + offset.y,
                                  1, 1);                
            }
        });
    });
}




function update() {
    draw();
    requestAnimationFrame(update);
}

const arena = createMatrix(25, 20); 

const player = {
    pos: {x: 0, y: 0},
    cube: cube
}

function playerMoveX(offset) {
    player.pos.x += offset;
    if (collide(arena, player)) {
        console.log('boom');
        player.pos.x -= offset;
    }
}

function playerMoveY(offset) {
    player.pos.y += offset;
    if (collide(arena, player)) {
        console.log('bemmm');
        player.pos.y -= offset;
    }
}

document.addEventListener('keydown', event => {
    if (event.keyCode === 37) {
        playerMoveX(-1)
        console.log('pressed left. X: ' + player.pos.x + ' Y: ' + player.pos.y);
    } else if (event.keyCode === 39) {
        playerMoveX(1)
        console.log('pressed right. X: ' + player.pos.x + ' Y: ' + player.pos.y);
    } else if (event.keyCode === 38) {
        playerMoveY(-1)
        console.log('pressed up. X: ' + player.pos.x + ' Y: ' + player.pos.y);
    } else if (event.keyCode === 40) {
        playerMoveY(1)
        console.log('pressed down. X: ' + player.pos.x + ' Y: ' + player.pos.y);
    }
})

update();
```

I'm having problems with:

```
function loadImage(url) {

    return new Promise(resolve => {
        const image = new Image();
        image.addEventListener('load', () => {
            resolve(image);
        });
        image.src = url;
    });
}
```

and:

```
loadImage('media/images/ball.png')
    .then(image => {
    context.drawImage(image, 100, 100);
    });
```

Maybe it's the order my functions are placed in? I don't know.

I want it to show my image in the canvas the rest i'll try to figure out my self I'm just at a wall at the moment.

Thanks for taking the time to read trough my question. If you're busy please don't feel obligated to answer.

Answer (score 0):

When I checking your code with jsfiddle. I have find that it is nothing wrong with the function you mentions. Below is the code I tried.

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas')
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")
//ctx.fillRect( 10, 10, 10, 10 )

function loadImage( url ) {
 let image = new Image()
  image.setAttribute( 'crossOrigin', 'Anonymous' )
  image.src = url
  return new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) => {
   image.addEventListener('load', function() {
     resolve( this )
    } )
  } )
}

loadImage( 'http://i.imgur.com/3tU4Vig.jpg' )
  .then( function( image ) {
   ctx.drawImage( image, 0, 0 )
  } )
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

I believe that the problem is the size of your canvas is too small.
Therefore, when you render the image in the canvas.
The image render outside of the canvas, so you cannot see any images in it.

Comment: Is that possible? I tried it without the rest of my code like you did. That works fine but when I add the other code it doesn't work anymore. Could it be the order of the functions or something? Is there anyway I could check in wich order my functions are loaded and if they load at all? That might help.

Comment: @Jeroen In your draw function, you have fill the whole canvas as a single color, which means that the image you render before will be overlay by the draw function. you may draw the image after the fillRect function.

Comment: Tried it but id doesn't seem to work unfortunately. Any other ideas?

Comment: It turns out my ball is behind the canvas. How do I get it in front?

Comment: In order to get it in the front, you may create a new function to render the ball every times after the fillRect or even after the drawCube. The render order is very important in canvas. You may overlay the image by fillRect, drawImage and also fillText.

Comment: A friendly recommendation is to create separate function for draw. For example, drawBackground, drawBall, drawPlayer, etc. Then, you can call the function with the order of background, player, ball. The last one to call always on the top of the canvas if you use Promise correctly.

Answer (score 0):

For me, this works fine. please check this.

https://codepen.io/samma89/pen/MRyGZM

Maybe you're missing this.

```
<canvas id="bitchinBlock"></canvas>
```

Comment: I don't think it is. I've got
```
<canvas id="bitchinBlock" width="500" height="400"></canvas>
```
as my html and I linked it correct to because I see then canvas and my block. Just not the image I want beside the block.